# Turn multiindex Series into Series of dict

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a Multiindex Series that looks like this:

```
a 1 value_1
  2 value_2
  3 value_3
b 2 value_4
  4 value_5
  5 value_6
c 1 value_7
  5 value_8
  9 value_9
```

I want to transform it into a single index Series, where the second level index are now dictionary keys, like so:

```
a {1: value_1, 2: value_2, 3: value_3}
b {2: value_4, 4: value_5, 5: value_6}
c {1: value_7, 5: value_8, 9: value_9}
```

I have tried converting to a dataframe then doing to_dict(), but the multiindex is getting returned as a tuple. All I want to do is to be able to decouple the first-level index from the second one- so any help that does that is also appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Series**

```
pd.Series({k: v[k].to_dict() for k, v in s.groupby(level=0)})

a    {1: 'value_1', 2: 'value_2', 3: 'value_3'}
b    {2: 'value_4', 4: 'value_5', 5: 'value_6'}
c    {1: 'value_7', 5: 'value_8', 9: 'value_9'}
dtype: object
```

**Dictionary**

```
{k: v[k].to_dict() for k, v in s.groupby(level=0)}

{'a': {1: 'value_1', 2: 'value_2', 3: 'value_3'},
 'b': {2: 'value_4', 4: 'value_5', 5: 'value_6'},
 'c': {1: 'value_7', 5: 'value_8', 9: 'value_9'}}
```

Comment: Worked wonderfully! A list comprehension method with no need for zip(). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If input is `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series({('c', 9): 'value_9', ('c', 1): 'value_7', ('b', 2): 'value_4', 
               ('a', 1): 'value_1', ('c', 5): 'value_8', ('a', 2): 'value_2', 
               ('b', 4): 'value_5', ('a', 3): 'value_3', ('b', 5): 'value_6'})
print (s)
a  1    value_1
   2    value_2
   3    value_3
b  2    value_4
   4    value_5
   5    value_6
c  1    value_7
   5    value_8
   9    value_9
dtype: object

s1 = (s.to_frame('D')
      .groupby(level=0)
      .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.index.get_level_values(1), x.D))))

print (s1)
a    {1: 'value_1', 2: 'value_2', 3: 'value_3'}
b    {2: 'value_4', 4: 'value_5', 5: 'value_6'}
c    {1: 'value_7', 5: 'value_8', 9: 'value_9'}
dtype: object

s = s.reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['level_1'], x[0])))
print (s)
a    {1: 'value_1', 2: 'value_2', 3: 'value_3'}
b    {2: 'value_4', 4: 'value_5', 5: 'value_6'}
c    {1: 'value_7', 5: 'value_8', 9: 'value_9'}
dtype: object
```

---

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom `lambda` function with `zip` and `dict`:

```
print (df)
           C
A B         
a 1  value_1
  2  value_2
  3  value_3
b 2  value_4
  4  value_5
  5  value_6
c 1  value_7
  5  value_8
  9  value_9

d = df.reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.B, x.C))).to_dict()
```

Or:

```
d = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.index.get_level_values(1),x.C))).to_dict()
```

---

```
print (d)
{'a': {1: 'value_1', 2: 'value_2', 3: 'value_3'}, 
 'c': {1: 'value_7', 5: 'value_8', 9: 'value_9'},
 'b': {2: 'value_4', 4: 'value_5', 5: 'value_6'}}
```

For output `Series` omit last `to_dict`.